# wordpress admin redirect loop

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect-loop, wp-admin

I've got a copy of our wordpress instance running inside a Docker container.
Our live instance works well but inside the docker container, I do get a redirect-loop as soon as I try to get access to wp-admin.

I've disabled all plugins, I've cleared my cache and so on but nothing worked so far.

OS is debian, similar to our live system. When I get the redirect-loop, there's no information written in my apache error.log-file.

Oh and this instance is accessible by using a subdomain. I had to rewrite all "www.domain.com" to "sub.domain.com".

If I can provide you with any informations to solve my problem just ask. I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Paddaels

Comment: You will need to change the urls in the database.

Comment: I've changed all "www.domain.com" inside the database to my subdomain. But I will check again, maybe I forgot a record. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missed some records in the database. The best approach is to use a tool like https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

If you download this free tool and upload to your server then it does a batch find-and-replace across every single table in your Wordpress database.

So, for example, replace http://www.example.com with http://sub.example.com

You can do a dry run and it will show you all the replaces that it will make. Once you're happy then click the "live run" button and all the changes are made.

I use this tool all the time when I am moving a site from my local machine to the live server. I also use the exact same approach when migrating a site from http to https

Comment: Great answer, only thing i would have added is 'make sure you remove the script from your server immediately after use'

Comment: Yes. Definitely do what Rich has said!

Comment: I've checked some things. First of all, If I try to connect to my site using port 80 or port 443, I can access it. Which is not really intended. It should always use port 443. However, if I try to access /wp-admin using http, I'll be redirected on https.
In my .htaccess file, I have a deactivated part for my redirect from port 80 to port 443. If I activate this part, I get a redirect-loop on my wp instance. That's what I've foudn so far.